# How to string Concatenate with 'ENTER' value in php

Tags: php

I need a method that concatenate string with enter. As an example my string `"Apple", "Box"`.

That string needs to be as:

```
$mynewstring = "Apple
                Box"
```

Not as:

`$mynewstring ="Apple "."\n"."Box"` or `$mynewstring ="Apple "."<br>"."Box"`

Please tell how to do this.

Comment: Looks like a coding formatting question. How are these strings stored? in an array or separate variables?

Comment: If you wonder about the downvote, it's there because your question makes no sense and there's a huge knowledge gap present. Just hit the enter key if you want to, no need to ask a question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like this..

```
<?php
$mynewstring = "Apple,Box";
$arr=explode(",",$mynewstring);
echo(implode(PHP_EOL,$arr));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Apple
Box
```

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is a part of DOM(browser related operation), then consider using **<br/>**, and use **\n** if using with php CLI.